# Marklogic - create indexes in collection?

Tags: marklogic

When I create indexes Marklogic goes and begins re-indexing all documents in the database. Is that possible to indexes only documents in collection that I want.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please explain more about what you're trying to accomplish, because I can't imagine any valid purpose to reindex only the docs in a collection. It's just not a thing that makes sense. So what is it you're trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider making your index more specific. It is always good to have meaningful element or property names, like `company-name` rather than just `name`.

Alternatively, you could also leverage the tree structure. If you have both companies and persons in your database, wrap contents in a root element or property that tells what it is, so that you can then create a path index on `company/name` or `person/name` specifically.

The (re)indexer is usually smart enough to figure out which documents are affected by indexes provided they are specific enough. It will potentially also save disk space, particularly if you can rule out a lot of irrelevant documents from such an index.

HTH!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot dictate what documents are re-indexed. However, you can turn off the auto-re-index feature and choose when to re-index.